# How to generate hibernate configuration file in Spring Tool Suite?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Spring Tool Suite for my Spring program. I am working on the spring code to integrate with hibernate which requires **hibernate configuration** file to be configured. How do i generate the XML file with proper DTD? My requirement is to generate the configuration automatically,as I use to generate my spring bean configuration file ? All I need is proper DTD for configuration file to come up while creating XML file. I get only two option while creating XML file :

1) **Spring Bean Configuration File**

2) **Spring Web Flow Definition File**

I explored the option in Spring Tool Suite but met with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to install [**Hibernate Tools**](http://hibernate.org/tools/) in STS you can follow [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-install-hibernate-tools-in-eclipse-ide/) tutorial, though it is for vanilla eclipse will work for STS too.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know STS doesn't provide this feature. I'm not sure about plugins. Anyway NetBeans provides this.

Anyway you can find proper DTD from Spring or Hibernate documentations.